# Error setting up geoip on Django

Tags: django, geolocation, geoip

I'm trying to add geolocation to a website, using GeoIP.  I followed the instructions on [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/), but I get this error: `ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware middleware: "cannot import name GeoIP"`  What can be missing?  I've added the geolocation function as a custom middleware as below:

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP

class LocationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        g = GeoIP()
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', None)
        if (not ip or ip == '127.0.0.1') and 
          request.META.has_key('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'):
            ip = request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
        if ip:
           city = g.city(ip)['city']
        else:
           # set default city

    return city
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems I got a solution after all.  The import statement should be:

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils.geoip import GeoIP
```