# Django GeoIP import

Tags: python, django, geoip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error setting up geoip on Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896996/error-setting-up-geoip-on-django)

I get the "cannot import name GeoIP" error from the browser but not on python terminal. for example for geodata in /tmp/geo. the following works in the python terminal.

```
    from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
    GeoIP(path='/tmp/geo/')
```

However the following in a django view gives the error

```
    from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
    return HttpResponse (GeoIP(path='/tmp/geo/'))
```

Any pointer will be helpfull. I'm using django 1.4 , python 2.6. here is the trace. Thanks.

```
    Traceback:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
    101.                             request.path_info)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
    300.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
    209.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
    216.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
    27.         result = func(*args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
    92.                 lookup_view = getattr(import_module(mod_name), func_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
    35.     __import__(name)
    File "/x/y/z/views.py" in <module>
    12. from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP

    Exception Type: ImportError at /
    Exception Value: cannot import name GeoIP
```

Comment: tried "from django.contrib.gis.utils.geoip import GeoIP" does not work either

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa I think this is no longer true as of django 1.4

Answer (score 5):

The two statements seem to differ (look at the stacktrace):

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP
```

vs

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
```

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geoip/__init__.py), `GeoIP` is defined in [`django.contrib.gis.geoip.base`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geoip/base.py) and imported in [`django.contrib.gis.geoip`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geoip/__init__.py), which explain why it works in the console, and not in the view, where you're using `django.contrib.gis.utils.GeoIP`.

You should therefore use `from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP` everywhere.

---

Your problem probably arises from the fact that the `django.contrib.gis.utils` module was [removed in Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/)

Comment: I've tried "from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP" and is not working

Comment: Can you try `from django.contrib.gis import geoip`, followed by `print geoip.HAS_GEOIP`? And give the result?

Comment: I get True at the prompt

Comment: @user1783848 If you get `True`, then `geoip.GeoIP` has to be defined. Is your django app running in the same virtual environment as your prompt?

Comment: Can you explain more. where and how do I need define it?

Comment: Sorry, Yes the environment is the same.

Comment: @user1783848 By has to, I meant that it wasn't possible that GeoIP wouldn't be defined. Can you confirm the traceback reports the appropriate path? Alternatively, in your view, can you try to import the geoip module but not the object itself? If that doesn't work, do you have access to the library? You could set up a small temporary hack to disable trapping the errors in the geoip import (see source), which could help you identify what went wrong.